# Fiori unable to load viz library while deploying in iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, sapui5, sap-fiori

I m trying to display the pie chart in the app. I used vizframe to achieve this. It is working fine. But once I deploy it in iphone it stop working.
In console it is showing
failed to load 'sap/viz/libs/sap-viz-info-framework.js'

when i check this path under resources directory. This file is not there. How to render the viz frame pie chart in iphone.

Comment: Which browser are you using on iphone? Safari?

How do you deploy the app to the iphone?
Could you please describe the steps for deployment?

Does the following example work in your iphone: [Sample: Pie](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.viz.sample.Pie/preview)

Comment: Yes, I deployed the app to the iphone. I am using same example as it is mentioned in UI5 explorer. The viz chart is working fine when I run on WebIDE.

Comment: As the viz chart is working fine on WebIDE, what happens, if you click on your iphone this link: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.viz.sample.Pie/preview ?
Does the PieChart come up ?
Could you please describe the exact steps, how you deploy the app on your iphone, so that we can investigate what the problem might be?

Comment: I have imported example zip file in my project. Then I turn on sap.viz lib from project setting and deployed the code in iPhone.

Comment: 1)
Could you please post a screenshot with the console error messages?

2)
Where did you get your “example zip file” from?

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest ensuring that your manifest file and index.html files have the required libraries imported at startup.

index.html:

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" .... data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m, sap.viz....">
```

manifest.json: (following is an example to use under sap.ui5 section)

"dependencies": {
            "minUI5Version": "1.36.0",
            "libs": {
                "sap.ui.core": {
                    "minVersion": "1.36.0"
                },
                "sap.m": {
                    "minVersion": "1.36.0"
                },
                "sap.ui.layout": {
                    "minVersion": "1.36.0"
                }
            }
        }

More information: [Link](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da.html)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution now. When you are deploying the application for WebIDE, make sure you are selecting release mode. Because other mode renames the library file by adding dbj at last. This is bug in SAP Fiori which I reported to them and they confirm me about this.